# Unity 5 Syncvar not working

Tags: unity, networking, synchronization

I have a cube in my scene. I want to change its color and I wanna server and all players to see it in this color. I have attached script on the cube:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Cube : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar(hook = "OnColorChanged")]
    public Color myColor;

    void OnColorChanged(Color value)
    {
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = myColor;
        Debug.Log(value + "," + myColor);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(myColor);
    }
}
```

I run `GameObject.FindWithTag("cube").GetComponent<Cube>().myColor = Color.red;`this in my host script when I want to change the color of the cube, but nothing happens. [image]

Comment: I had some issues with SyncVars, mostly because I was using a type that wasn't supported by the attribute or because on compilation a UNET warning was triggered containing the error.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on SyncVar:

- These variables will have their values sychronized **from the server to clients** in the game that are in the ready state.

Its possible that you are applying the change on a client.

SyncVars only sync changes from the server to the clients. If you want to update a SyncVar from a client, make the client send a `Command` from the client to the server that updates the value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I apply the change in my host script, so from server to client.

Comment: I see. Where are you executing the code `GameObject.FindWithTag("cube").GetComponent<Cube>().myColor = Color.red;`?

Comment: In my host script

Comment: I mean in which gameObject is the script. Is it on the cube? The NetworkManager?

Comment: The network manager

Comment: There are my 3 scripts: http://pastebin.com/TT43eQU2

Comment: Are you sure you are reaching that line? Try to run it at the very beginning of the Update(), instead inside the countdown conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45241/discussion-between-sudoman281-and-leon).